# Cannot set system default Desktop Environment

Tags: gnome, gdm, default

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I completely uninstalled `Unity` and `lightdm`, and installed `Gnome 3` with `gdm`. Now I can log into Gnome Desktop by selecting Gnome from log in screen. However, if I select `System Default` then no desktop appears. The system just remains blank. I tried setting gnome in `~/.dmrc` file as was suggested in some post. I looked in gdm wiki but can't seem to solve the issue. Can anyone help?